# How to convert TIFF scan file to JPEG or PNG general file format in Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, scanning, convert

How can i convert this scanned file to general JPEG/PNG?

I used `scanimage --mode=color --format=tiff > /tmp/testing.tiff` from a scanner

```
$ convert -seperate testing.tiff testing.jpeg
convert: unrecognized option `-seperate' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2667.

$ convert -seperate -format jpg testing.tiff testing.jpg
convert: unrecognized option `-seperate' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2667.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command is `convert -separate image1 image2`, no need for further options.

Comment: you don't even need the -separate bit. "convert image_from.tiff image_to.png" works well etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try `-separate` instead of `-seperate`

Reference: [convert man page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this converter?
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Audio%2BVideo%2BImage%2BText%2BISO+Convert?content=92533

Download the file, right-click on it, go to the permissions tab and check the "Allow to execute this file as a program" box.

Go to your home folder, press CTRL+H (you will see the hidden files), copy and paste the file to .gnome2>Nautilus scripts.

Close Nautilus, right-click on the file you want to convert, go to Scripts, click on the converter, and follow the instructions.