# Convert folder with tiff to jpg by using mozjpg

Tags: image-processing, mozilla

I hear that `mozjpeg` is a nice jpeg compressor from Mozilla. How can I convert my folder with *.tiff to jpg from terminal using mozjpeg?

Comment: TIFF is a container. Chances are that your images are already in JPEG format, just wrapped inside TIFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked all man-pages

```
/usr/share/man/man1/djpeg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/jpegtran.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wrjpgcom.1
/usr/share/man/man1/rdjpgcom.1
```

but I think I have to disappoint you. You can't convert images from TIFF to JPEG with any of these programs.

---

After the installation with the steps described in Rinzwind answer I have installed the deb. The following files are installed:

Output of `dpkg -L mozjpeg`

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/cjpeg
/usr/bin/djpeg
/usr/bin/rdjpgcom
/usr/bin/tjbench
/usr/bin/wrjpgcom
/usr/bin/jpegtran
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62.2.0
/usr/lib/libturbojpeg.a
/usr/lib/libturbojpeg.so.0.1.0
/usr/lib/libjpeg.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/djpeg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/jpegtran.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wrjpgcom.1
/usr/share/man/man1/rdjpgcom.1
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/wizard.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/usage.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/libjpeg.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/structure.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/README
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/README-turbo.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/README-mozilla.txt
/usr/share/doc/mozjpeg-3.1/example.c
/usr/include
/usr/include/jconfig.h
/usr/include/turbojpeg.h
/usr/include/jmorecfg.h
/usr/include/jerror.h
/usr/include/jpeglib.h
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/libturbojpeg.so
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/libturbojpeg.so.0
```

Comment: What is this long list? Maybe you can say, how can I build from source (or install deb) of mozjpeg? This project did not have any documentation...

Comment: I undeleted my answer (it was about how to compile it) BUT it looks like you can NOT use it for tiff.

Comment: The long list shows all installed files via a deb install

Answer (score 4):

You will have to build `mozjpeg` from source.

If you do have the packages to compile it, you can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config git
```

- Fetch the source code with:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg.git
  ```
- Build it with:

  ```
  cd mozjpeg
  autoreconf -fiv
  ./configure --prefix=/usr
  make
  ```

You will have 2 options: to install with the command:

```
make install
```

or to create a "deb" (that you then can use to install) with:

```
make deb
```

---

But it does not seem to support "tiff".  So you need to extract the files 1st. See [How to convert TIFF scan file to JPEG or PNG general file format in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72125/how-to-convert-tiff-scan-file-to-jpeg-or-png-general-file-format-in-ubuntu) for that.

This is a generic command to compress a jpg to 75%:

```
convert filename1.jpg pnm:- | cjpeg -quality 75 > filename2.jpg
```

The `jpegtran` tool can be used to optimise an image:

```
jpegtran -outfile filename1.jpg -optimise -copy none filename2.jpg
```

---

If you get any errors please edit your question and I'll have a look.